# Android:Update Multiple EditTexts in a ListView via Buttons that are part of the ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am new to android and I would like to ask something ,that I searched for in several threads and couldn't find a specific  solution.

I would like to make a listView that looks like this:

http://postimg.org/image/9ib8gjq95/

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//TextView//EditText//Button+//Button-//

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

This listView is dynamically updated with new rows of the same mode(TextView,EditText,Button+,Button-).

I want to click on the +/- Buttons of a row and change the number that exists in the EditText in this row.

> ```
> package com.example.test2;
>
> import java.util.ArrayList;
>
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.content.Context;
> import android.view.LayoutInflater;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.view.ViewGroup;
> import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
> import android.widget.Button;
> import android.widget.EditText;
> import android.widget.TextView;
>
>
> public class EditCAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Prosthesi> {
> int counter=0;
>
> Context context;
> String onoma;
> int layoutResourceId;
> ArrayList<Prosthesi> data = new ArrayList<Prosthesi>();
>
>
> public EditCAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
> ArrayList<Prosthesi> data) {
> super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
> this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
> this.context = context;
> this.data = data;
> }
>
> @Override
> public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
> View row3 = convertView;
>  UserHolder holder = null;
>
> if (row3 == null) {
> LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
> row3 = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
> holder = new UserHolder();
> holder.kodikos=(TextView)row3.findViewById(R.id.textD);
> holder.plus = (Button) row3.findViewById(R.id.buttD);
> holder.minus=(Button) row3.findViewById(R.id.buttD2);
> holder.posotita=(EditText)row3.findViewById(R.id.e4);
>
> row3.setTag(holder);
> } else {
> holder = (UserHolder) row3.getTag();
> }
> Prosthesi user = data.get(position);
> holder.kodikos.setText(user.getName());
>
> holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>   @Override
>   public void onClick(View v) {
>       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>       counter++;
>
>       //do the stuff I described
>
>          //tried this but it isn't working!
>         //   UserHolder holder=(UserHolder)v.getTag();
>        // holder.posotita.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
>
>   }
> });
>
> return row3;
> }
>
>
>
>
>
>
> static class UserHolder {
> TextView kodikos;
> EditText posotita;
> Button plus;
> Button minus;
>
>
>
>
>  }
>
>  }
> ```

thnx in advance!!!!

Comment: hey you got any answer?if yes then please tell me

Answer (score 0):

actually this way you will not be able to get which row edittext you need to change. so first of all set tag for both the buttons then initialize the counter inside getview and according to button behavior on setonclicklistner change the value on edittext. this will work for sure. please try it and tell me if you need more help.